# VueJS multiple selection

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I tried to multiple select with select2 
i used laravel and my data on userRoles is returned data on User model with relation roles, and allRoles is just all in Role model
code on view

```
<select class="form-control" name="roles[]" id="roles"  multiple>
            <option v-for="role in allRoles"
                    :value="role.id"
                    >
                @{{ role.name }}
            </option>
 </select>
```

how to set selected options using userRoles array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `computed` hashMap (object) to search for selected roles:

```
computed: {
    selectedRoleMap() {
        var map = {};
        this.userRoles.forEach(role => {
            map[role] = 1;
        });
        return map;
    }
}
```

Then add `:selected="selectedRoleMap.hasOwnProperty(role.id)"` to `option`s.

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/df7j8xhz/

Alternatively, you can add a `hasRole` `method` to loop through `userRoles` to see if an `id` is in `userRoles`, but build a hashMap and search in it has a better performance than looping the array `allRoles.length` times.

Comment: @Rai Why do you need that array? Your problem is making some of the `options`s selected right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129141/discussion-between-panjunjie-and-rai).

Comment: @Rai Let us continue this discussion in chat.